# CanvasJS chart not updating with AJAX callback values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, canvasjs

I have a Django app that calculates the CPU usage %, memory usage, and some other stats in a view. In another view, I have a huge function that takes some minutes to complete. I want to chart the changing CPU statistics as the function is executing, i.e., as the function is executing, I'm making periodic AJAX calls to the CPU statistics view, and updating CanvasJS datapoints with the new CPU statistics parameters to update the chart.

Here's the JavaScript for the chart drawing -

```
var dataPoints = [];

var cpu = 0;
var mem = 0;
var mem_info = 0;

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                title: {
                    text: "Machine Stats"
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints: dataPoints
                }]
            });

function callCharts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'charting/',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            cpu = data.cpu;
            mem = data.mem;
            mem_info = data.mem_info;

            dps = [{x: 10, y: cpu, label: "CPU %"}, 
                               {x: 20, y: mem, label: "Memory %"}, 
                               {x: 30, y: mem_info, label: "Memory in MB"}, 
                               //{x: 40, y: }
                               ];

            dataPoints.push(dps);
            chart.render();
        }
    });
}

$('#chartbutton').on("click", function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'aftercharting/',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    });

    var intervalID = setInterval(function() {callCharts();}, 1000);

});
```

`cpu` stores the CPU usage %, `mem` stores the memory usage % and `mem_info` stores the memory usage in RAM.

When I click on `#chartButton`, an AJAX call happens to `aftercharting`, which has the huge function. Since it's an asynchronous call, I'm calling `callCharts()` immediately after in a `setInterval`. `callCharts()` then makes AJAX calls to `charting` periodically to get new CPU statistics, and using them, I'm updating the datapoints. But it doesn't seem to work.

I'm getting a blank chart with only the X-axis populated with some values which are updated after the AJAX calls to `\charting`.

In case it's required, these are the two Django views -

```
def charting(request):
    cpu, mem, cpu_time, mem_info = getPythonProgSystemInfo()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'cpu': cpu, 'mem': mem, 'cpu_time': cpu_time, 'mem_info': mem_info}))

def aftercharting(request):
    sleep(5)
    return HttpResponse("from django, but should come after")
```

Right now, `aftercharting\` doesn't have that huge program, but the `sleep()` function does a similar job of making it wait.

**EDIT:**

I've looked up [here](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/live-updating-javascript-charts-json-api-ajax/), and here's my updated code -

```
var dataPoints = [];
var intervalID = 0;
var chart = 0;

var cpu = 0;
var mem = 0;
var mem_info = 0;

function updateChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'charting/',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            dataPoints.push({x: 10, y: cpu, label: 'CPU %'});
            dataPoints.push({x: 10, y: mem, label: 'Memory %'});
            dataPoints.push({x: 30, y: mem_info, label: 'Memory in MB'});
            chart.render();
            intervalID = setInterval(function() {updateChart();}, 1000);
        }
    });
}

function callChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'charting/',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            cpu = data.cpu;
            mem = data.mem;
            mem_info = data.mem_info;

            dps = [{x: 10, y: cpu, label: "CPU %"}, 
                              {x: 20, y: mem, label: "Memory %"}, 
                              {x: 30, y: mem_info, label: "Memory in MB"}, 
                              //{x: 40, y: }
                              ];

                chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                title: {
                    text: "Machine Stats"
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints: dps
                }]
            });
            chart.render();
            updateChart();
        }, 
    });
}

$('#chartbutton').on("click", function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'aftercharting/',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        },
    });
    callChart();
});
```

But it's still not working. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure the data returned from django is correct?

Comment: @dentemm - I've edited my code, so you can see my Django views. `charting()` returns a JSON object, so the format is correct. Even if the CPU percentages that are calculated from `getPythonProgSystemInfo()` are incorrect, they must be some values, which should populate the chart. Besides, I've checked through the console, that the values are correct.